# Frequency of operation of typical laptop's 5V switching regulator powering USB ports

Tags: power-supply, usb, filter, switch-mode-power-supply, passive-networks

What lowest frequency should I expect from a modern laptop? I need to calculate a filter for powering some analog circuitry from USB.

Comment: Anything from ~100kHz for a crummy cheapo unit to several MHz for a high end one. So to be safe, assume 50kHz and then stick a high speed LDO after the filter to drop any residual noise, there are several LDOs with half decent noise filtering out to a MHz of so (even a couple out to 10MHz)

Comment: It's not just the switching frequency you have to worry about. USB +5V is potentially noisy at all frequencies because other devices could be drawing intermittent currents from it. So either filter to below the lowest frequency your analog circuitry is sensitive to, or regulate the voltage.